# Create New Type with Label Inside C#

Tags: c#, custom-data-type

I want to create a new type in c# with a label in it. I have made a new class:

```
public class collection
{
    public Label Link { get; set; }
    public Label Title { get; set; }

    public collection()
    {
    }

    public collection(Label link, Label title)
    {
        this.Link = link;
        this.Title = title;
    }
}
```

But when I then make a new array

```
collection[] col = new collection[100];
```

and try to put new labels on it:

```
col[i].Title = new Label();
col[i].link = new Label();
```

it doesn't work, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Just a minor tip for the next time, add the error message that you get to the question. Or explain how it does not work. It was fine this time, but for more complicated questions its often a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper initialization of collection looks like that:

```
collection[] col = new collection[100];
for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++)
{
  col[i] = new collection();
  col[i].Title = new Label();
  col[i].link = new Label();
}
```

You can use either second constructor and then looks like that:

```
collection[] col = new collection[100];
for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++)
{
  col[i] = new collection(new Label(), new Label());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following line:

```
collection[] col = new collection[100];
```

creates an array that can holds 100 references to objects of type `collection`.

Initially all the items of this array would be null. You have to create `collection` items and then store their references to this array.

For instance `col[0]`, or `col[1]`, etc... are `null`. If you try the following:

```
col[0].Title
```

you would get a null reference exception.

So you have first to create a new object as:

```
col[0] = new collection(new Label(), new Label());
```

or like:

```
col[0] = new collection();
col[0].Title = new Label();
col[0].Link = new Label();
```